# How to change default theme color teal to blue without using custom CSS in materilaize

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm working with materialize and I'm trying to not touch your code, so that I can just upgrade it when a new version arrives, but I want to change the primary color and I can't find an easy way to just switch the whole thing to say the blue palette.

I heard about sass but I don't know how to use it

This is my CSS and JS file how to reuse it

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sass/materialize.scss">
<script src="js/bin/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sass is very easy, install sass cli in your system

```
gem install sass
```

The base color you want to change was inside the below folder

> materialize-src/sass/components/_color.scss

- Do the required changes
- just run the below code in terminal

  sass materialize.scss materialize.css

RUN while you are inside the **scss** folder of the **materialize-src**

> materialize-src/sass/

replace the newly created **materialize.css** file in your existing **project**.

You could even create a minified version of your new file by using https://cssminifier.com/ and save file with name materialize.min.css

Fore more reference on sass please look into the following link [SASS Simple DOC](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

UPDATE - as per request

Give me the color codes as per your requirement by replacing the below i will generate your file by the same procedure i have explained above.

```
$teal: (
  "base":       #009688,
  "lighten-5":  #e0f2f1,
  "lighten-4":  #b2dfdb,
  "lighten-3":  #80cbc4,
  "lighten-2":  #4db6ac,
  "lighten-1":  #26a69a,
  "darken-1":   #00897b,
  "darken-2":   #00796b,
  "darken-3":   #00695c,
  "darken-4":   #004d40,
  "accent-1":    #a7ffeb,
  "accent-2":    #64ffda,
  "accent-3":    #1de9b6,
  "accent-4":    #00bfa5
);
```

Comment: simple how to change teal color to blue color using sass.give me simple html page for example

Comment: you want teal should appear as blue color? you want to change teal in blue.

Comment: If you want just teal replaced with blue.. you can just write 'blue' in the place of 'teal' - http://materializecss.com/color.html.  If that is not the case you change entire teal color into blue by changing _color.scss but it will cause the entire teal palette color and that will show as blue forever until you change it back.. Other than that you can create your own palette - name it was your own. If you want me to do that then send me the required color set for your new Palette.

Comment: each and every place i need to change blue instead of teal.Thats why I am asking, experts say use Sass .But i dont know how to use sass .I am using CentOS

Comment: Check the update in the answer. give me the replaced colors i will give you the new **materialize.css**

Comment: you help me alot but didnt understand that how to install sass and how to utilize that.I will give you tick ok va. If you have time i will give you my machine in teamviewermy email id -symonkt@gmail.com thanks dev kishore

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use like this by defining it in head tags

```
<style>
* {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

IF you use this universal styling it will applied on your whole page in same way you should use if you using paragraphs heading tags or some thing else just define your tags in this curly brackets with your own styles .